# How to access the javascript variable inside html tags

Tags: javascript

I wanted to added javascript variable inside html code.
Here is my code:

```
 <select id="currentrun" name="currentrun" >
        <option value=""><script>selectedrun</script></option>
 </select>
```

and my js function

```
 var currentrun="";
 var selectedrun="";
  function setCurrentRun()
  { 
    currentrun = document.getElementById("runlist");
    selectedrun = currentrun.options[currentrun.selectedIndex].value;       
   }
```

But this doesn't work.

Can anyone help me to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use the Id of the element to obtain the element by 'getElementById' method, e.g. document.getElementById("currentrun"). And there is no selectedIndex for the html elements.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to run the script like that.

The value of the currentrun can be retrieved as:

```
document.getElementById('currentrun').value
```

And for completeness, if you want to trigger a JavaScript function call each time the selection is modified, do this:

```
<select onchange="my_function();">
  <option>...</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to set the text of the `option` element with javascript. Here is one way you can do it using the `id` of the element to get it and then set the `text` property of the element to your javascript variable:

```
<select id="currentrun" name="currentrun" >
    <option id="currentoption" value=""></option>
</select>

<script>
    document.getElementById("currentoption").text = selectedrun;     
</script>
```

Be sure to put any necessary javascript that declares and sets the `selectedrun` variable before the above script.